# Is this normal new HD SMART Health?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, hard-drive-recovery

Temperature is around 49ºC / 120ºF

Also, it is making a noise like if there was dust inside it.

What can I do?!

[image]

Comment: Can you describe the noise better or get us a recording of it? Does it sound like whirring, clicking, grinding, ringing, scraping?

Comment: I would say scraping, but not so treble (I hope this is the right term)

Comment: You have high amount of reallocated sectors and CRC errors if you hear a scraping noise and that scraping noise is new it means your HDD is failing.

Comment: Doesn't look like normal for a new HDD, it looks more like a failing HDD. You should RMA this drive.

Comment: Thanks guys, indeed I will RMA this. I bought it only 5 days ago.